# Как сделать так, чтобы команда random сделала случайный никнейм?

Tags: случайные-числа, python-3.7

Мне нужно вместо рандомных значений наподобии hij23 любой ник имеющий всегда гласные,тоисть чтобы был сам никнейм а не каша,заранее спасибо.

```py
print(''.join([random.choice(list('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM')) for x in range(5)]))
```

Comment: Приведите примеры годных никнеймов, так ничего непонятно.

Comment: буквоцифры больше похожи на пароль, а не ник. чтобы было читабельное имя нужно хотябы чередование гласных и согласных буков, а циферка только в конце.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня независимо получилось что-то похожее на то, что у Zhihar и спасибо также MrRob0257 за идею:

```
import random

def gen_random_nick():
    for i in range(random.randint(3, 6)):
        if i % 2:
            yield random.choice('eyuioa')
        else:
            yield random.choice('qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm')
    for i in range(random.randint(1, 4)):
        yield random.choice('1234567890')

for _ in range(10):
    print(str.title(''.join(gen_random_nick())))
```

Вывод:

```
Jucy12
Teti566
Xiduva546
Mape469
Fijyfu2
Wehora0487
Mov6
Nogan218
Lurux27
Qafis474
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь,уже решил проблемку)

Answer (score 3):

да хоть так:

```
import random

vowels = 'aeiouy'
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
digits = '01234567890'
symbols = '!@'

size = 7
number_part_size = random.randint(0, size // 2)

part1 = [random.choice(consonants) for i in range(size)]
part2 = [random.choice(vowels) for i in range(size)]
part3 = [random.choice(digits) for i in range(number_part_size)]

login_part = ''.join(obj[0] + obj[1] for obj in zip(part1, part2))

login = login_part[:size - number_part_size] + ''.join(part3)

print(login)
```

но правила формирования ника всё-таки лучше регламентировать

Comment: А чтойто `symbols` нигде не используется? )

Comment: @CrazyElf да я подумал куда им в никнейм - но можно в начало или конец поставить или например гласные `о` заменить на `@` или `0` случайно

Comment: Можно ещё большие-маленькие буквы чередовать, так то до бесконечности можно придумывать

Comment: @CrazyElf, вообще лучше найти таблицу слогов английских слов и словарь слов и можно собирать тогда никнеймы похожие на слова (словарь слов нужен, чтобы не было совпадений) - вообще в тех же MMORPG есть же генераторы гномих, людских, эльфийских и т.д. имен - вот примерно такой генератор можно и сделать :)

Comment: Я бы вообще нейросеть припахал, но это уж совсем будет ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, тогда могут пойти имена типа "Макс Бычий Цепень" :)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит попробовать использовать пары согласная/гласная.
Так же можно поэкспериментировать на добавление гласной вначале и согласной в конце.